Sun Pump ошибка Python
Пытаюсь, что-то сделать с этим контрактом: https://docs.sun.io/developers/swap/smart-router
В итоге дошел до того, что все отрпавляется, но дает ошибку на скрине.
Вроде все посылаю так, как надо по документации
Но мои trx не хоят меняться на нужный токен.
Ссылка на транзакцию: https://tronscan.org/#/transaction/6754e409ab4fc36d2d3df0a972d8ac01b038f2e86e8258aa5d4bffb7f796d527
Так подписываю транзакцию:
# Построение и подписание транзакции
signed_txn = (
    smart_router.functions.swapExactInput.with_transfer(amount_in)(
        best_route['tokens'],
        best_route['poolVersions'],
        [len(best_route['tokens'])],
        [int(num) for num in best_route['poolFees']],
        [
            amount_in,
            1,
            address,
            1662825600
        ]
    )
    .with_owner(address)
    .fee_limit(1_000_000_000)
    .build()
    .sign(private_key_obj)
)

